# How to force the use of SSL for some URL of my Django Application?

Tags: django, apache, mod-rewrite, ssl, wsgi

I want to be sure that for some URL of my website, SSL will be use.
I saw a lot of answer already on SO.

[Force redirect to SSL for all pages apart from one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724968/force-redirect-to-ssl-for-all-pages-apart-from-one)

So I think I will use `mod_rewrite`.

My question is more about how to configure the **Virtual Host** to run my **Django Application** over `HTTP` and over `HTTPS` without problems. I am using `WSGI`.

Is it a problem to just duplicate the configuration over `*:443` and over `*:80`?
What should I do to have the best configuration?

Comment: I'd suggest you find the answer at serverfault.com.

Comment: Ok here we go : http://serverfault.com/questions/73257/how-to-force-the-use-of-ssl-for-some-url-of-my-django-application

Comment: Maybe this is related : http://effbot.org/zone/django-multihost.htm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If by WSGI you actually mean Apache/mod_wsgi, then although mounted WSGI applications normally get run in their own sub interpreters, the 80/443 split is a special case and even though in different VirtualHost so long as mount point for WSGIScriptAlias, and the ServerName are the same, they will be merged.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com

WSGIScriptAlias / /some/path/django.wsgi.
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.example.com

WSGIScriptAlias / /some/path/django.wsgi.
</VirtualHost>
```

This will happen for daemon mode as well, but with daemon mode you need to define only a single daemon process group in first VirtualHost definition and then just refer to that from both with WSGIProcessGroup.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com

WSGIDaemonProcess mydjangosite ...
WSGIProcessGroup mydjangosite

WSGIScriptAlias / /some/path/django.wsgi.
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:444>
ServerName www.example.com

WSGIProcessGroup mydjangosite

WSGIScriptAlias / /some/path/django.wsgi.
</VirtualHost>
```

The WSGIProcessGroup can only reach across like to that VirtualHost for same ServerName.

Django provides a is_secure() method for determining when request came via HTTPS which derives from WSGI variable with request called 'wsgi.url_scheme' which is set by mod_wsgi.

So, you would have one single Django WSGI script file and settings file. You just need to duplicate application mounting as decsribed in Apache/mod_wsgi configuration.

Answer (score 11):

Besides using mod_rewrite, you can also use Django to control the SSL redirects.

Here's a modified version of a middleware from the [Satchmo Project](http://www.satchmoproject.com/). I tend to like this method better than mod_rewrite as it's easier to manage.

To use it, pass 'SSL':True into your url conf:

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('some_site.some_app.views',
        (r'^test/secure/$','test_secure',{'SSL':True}),
    )
```

Here's the middleware code:

```
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, get_host

    SSL = 'SSL'

    def request_is_secure(request):
        if request.is_secure():
            return True

        # Handle forwarded SSL (used at Webfaction)
        if 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL' in request.META:
            return request.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL'] == 'on'

        if 'HTTP_X_SSL_REQUEST' in request.META:
            return request.META['HTTP_X_SSL_REQUEST'] == '1'

        return False

    class SSLRedirect:
        def process_request(self, request):
            if request_is_secure(request):
                request.IS_SECURE=True
            return None

        def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):          
            if SSL in view_kwargs:
                secure = view_kwargs[SSL]
                del view_kwargs[SSL]
            else:
                secure = False

            if settings.DEBUG:
                return None

            if getattr(settings, "TESTMODE", False):
                return None

            if not secure == request_is_secure(request):
                return self._redirect(request, secure)

        def _redirect(self, request, secure):
            if settings.DEBUG and request.method == 'POST':
                raise RuntimeError(
                """Django can't perform a SSL redirect while maintaining POST data.
                    Please structure your views so that redirects only occur during GETs.""")

            protocol = secure and "https" or "http"

            newurl = "%s://%s%s" % (protocol,get_host(request),request.get_full_path())

            return HttpResponseRedirect(newurl)
```

Comment: This is useful too. To be sure that it is a SSL connexion. Do you think it is better to handle it with django. Or with Mod_Rewrite ?

Comment: Like I mentioned, I tend to like managing it in Django, as it's easier to see what URLs are secured via SSL. If you need to secure a URL, just update the urls.py file, and you're done. No messy (well, messier) mod_rewrite rules needed.

Comment: I believe the code above is missing the final line of the _redirect() function...the final line of that function should be `return HttpResponseRedirect(newurl)`

Comment: I placed it in my project root directory in a file called `ssl_redirect.py` and in `settings.py` added a line to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` for `'ssl_redirect.SSLRedirect'`.  
  Also, note that in Django 1.5 you need to change the get_host call to `request.get_host()` and remove the get_host import at the top, or you'll get an error about unable to import get_host.

Comment: This code is trusting user provided headers, **which is insecure** unless you're behind a proxy that strips unexpected headers. You should just check `.is_secure` and configure `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER` appropriately for your setup.

Comment: If you use Django and only put some URLs as HTTPS, then data like your session can be leaked. Plus, if you manage it through Django, you have to use the same decorator everywhere, and remember to use it when you create a new view. It's much easier and safer to just use apache/nginx.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a view decorator that you can apply to the views that should have HTTPS.

```
from functools import wraps
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


def require_https(view):
    """A view decorator that redirects to HTTPS if this view is requested
    over HTTP. Allows HTTP when DEBUG is on and during unit tests.

    """

    @wraps(view)
    def view_or_redirect(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.is_secure():
            # Just load the view on a devserver or in the testing environment.
            if settings.DEBUG or request.META['SERVER_NAME'] == "testserver":
                return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

            else:
                # Redirect to HTTPS.
                request_url = request.build_absolute_uri(request.get_full_path())
                secure_url = request_url.replace('http://', 'https://')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(secure_url)

        else:
            # It's HTTPS, so load the view.
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return view_or_redirect
```

Answer (score 0):

We used some simple middleware to check urls against a list of base urls that *must* be in HTTPS mode, all others are forced to HTTP mode. The big caveat here is that any POST data can be lost unless you take extra care (it didn't matter in our case). We were doing this on join pages that required credit card numbers and the like so as soon as they were in that pipeline we forced them into HTTPS.