# Serving secure Django pages with HTTPS

Tags: python, django, deployment, https

What is the proper deployment configuration for a Django application that needs some pages served with HTTPS and others with HTTP?
I want to use HTTPS for the pages that involve registration and inputting passwords.  I want to use HTTP for all other pages.

Comment: Try http://www.redrobotstudios.com/blog/2009/02/18/securing-django-with-ssl/.

Comment: What katrielalex suggested. This won't tell you how to work out a mixture of HTTP and HTTPS pages but it is worth checking out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no single approach as far as I know.  You can use a decorator `secure_required` as developed in this post by Scott Barnham:

- [Securing Django with SSL](http://www.redrobotstudios.com/blog/2009/02/18/securing-django-with-ssl/)

or use middleware:

- [SSLMidleware](http://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/wiki/ContributedMiddleware/SSLMiddleware.2.py)

If you're looking for deployment information with respect to Apache and mod_wsgi, then Graham Dumpleton provides a nice answer in this question:

- [How to force the use of SSL for some URL of my Django Application ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548210/how-to-force-the-use-of-ssl-for-some-url-of-my-django-application/1549661#1549661)