# Can portions of a python web app be secure while others are not?

Tags: python, django, ssl

I am looking at switching to python/django for my web development. For some of the application I would need to port I have admin sections of the site being served over SSL while the main interface is not.

Is there a way to serve up say the admin portion of a django app over SSL while the rest of the site is over HTTP?

Comment: this has to do with your webserver configuration (apache or other) rahter than your code in Django. Also, django allows you to user a decorator function  (login_required) for as many pages as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its definitely possible. If you are using `nginx`, this how you would do it:

Under `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, add the following below your server tag and configure the files appropriately:

```
    #SSL Support added
    listen   443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/ssl/nginx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/ssl/nginx/server.key;
    ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
```

Then in your middleware.py,

```
class SecureRequiredMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.paths = getattr(settings, 'SECURE_REQUIRED_PATHS')
        self.enabled = self.paths and getattr(settings, 'HTTPS_SUPPORT')

    def process_request(self, request):
        if self.enabled and not request.is_secure():
            for path in self.paths:
                if request.get_full_path().startswith(path):
                    request_url = request.build_absolute_uri(request.get_full_path())
                    secure_url = request_url.replace('http://', 'https://')
                    print self.paths, request_url, secure_url
                    return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(secure_url)
        return None
```

Then in settings.py,

```
....
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'djo.middleware.SecureRequiredMiddleware',
....
HTTPS_SUPPORT = True
SECURE_REQUIRED_PATHS = (
    r'/admin/',
)
```

That should get you started.

Comment: Also good:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548210/how-to-force-the-use-of-ssl-for-some-url-of-my-django-application/1549661#1549661